# Adding data in a row which already existing column in tableau

Tags: tableau-api

I need to add the extra rows in a column in tableau. Below i have add a example

Output

```
**Name** 
  raj
  ravi
```

Excepted output

```
**Name** 
  raj
  ravi
  ram
```

Can someone help me to add the value in tableau

Comment: You should add the data to your source file, not in Tableau. Tableau is a data visualization tool, not a tool for data entry.

Comment: I don't have permission to add the data to source file

Comment: As @ben-p stated you cannot inject data from Tableau. You may create an SQL view and inject the data in that view and use that view from Tableau. Or another solution can be found if you explain your exact scenario.

Comment: @HakanERDOGAN i will try but my source file is a excel file

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tableau is designed as a read-only viewer of data. That decision has many advantages for performance, scalability and reliability, and supports many use cases.

Tableau data sources point to external data stores; they don't contain the data.  Tableau leaves the data at rest and sends queries to the data store when it needs information. This architecture avoids proprietary vendor silos that lock in your data, and allows Tableau to be used with many different types of databases and files as long as you have read-access to the data. It also scales to very large cloud sized databases.

If you wish to append data rows to your original data store, but don't have write permission to the data, that's a question for your data owner.

However, if you wish to append data to your visualization without modifying your external data set, one approach is put your new data rows in a store that you can control (such as an Excel file), and then use the UNION feature available from the data source pane to combine data rows from both sources into your your Tableau data source.

Then your visualization will be based on both the original and "new" data rows, and you can separately decide whether or not to send the new data rows back to the data owner to incorporate into the original data file.

Comment: Thanks alex. Now it’s fine. I have created a new sheet with required data and i done union

Answer (score -3):

Some data sources allow data to be appended. Go to one of the worksheet, in the data card right-click the data source and select append.

Comment: Kurt H is probably talking about data extracts. Extracts are a persistent cache containing an indexed, potentially filtered/aggregated copy of data from an original source. You can append to an extract, but that is very different from appending to the original data source.